# Moving agents using another agent for 2 movements

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to have my forklift agent move a pallet agent. My model works when the forklift agent has 1 movement, say from Source to Storage1.
I numbered the nodes in the image, as now I need the same population of forklifts, ForkliftStore (Home = 1), to be waiting to move a pallet either from Storage1 (2) to Storage2 (3) OR from Storage2 (3) to Line1Start (4). The model does not allow the source for ForkliftStore, where I inject my forklifts upon initializing the model, to be connected to two delay nodes.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I would like to keep the forklifts as a population of agents rather than resources, as I can better control other areas of the model with this.[image]

Comment: Sorry to say but this looks like you fundamentally model wrong. Resources like forklifts are not typically created/destroyed in flow charts. They are seized/released from agents like parcels to be transported in/out of storages. If you model like this, your fundamental problem vanishes. Pls do ALL the step-by-step tutorials in the AnyLogic help to learn more: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a new function f_precheckStore and combine all forklifts into a enter-exit flow. The movement of a forklift from the different locations is defined by a v_movementNbr that is passed to the f_precheckStore in each pallet precheck block.
f_precheckStore:

```
//Check if there is forklift available
Forklift fl = findFirst(delayForkliftHome, a->a.v_inUse==false);
if (fl==null) {
    traceln("Forklift is a constraint");
    return;
}
//forkliftStoreAtHome1.get(0);

//Determine movement based on movementNum
fl.v_movementNbr = movementNbr;
if (movementNbr==1 && v_inventoryRawMat < p_capacityRawMat) {
    fl.v_inUse = true;
    delayForkliftHome.stopDelay(fl);
    //variable++;
} else if (movementNbr==2 && v_inventoryMinIng < p_capacityMinIng) {
    fl.v_inUse = true;
    delayForkliftHome.stopDelay(fl);
    //variable++;
} else if (movementNbr==3) {
    fl.v_inUse = true;
    delayForkliftHome.stopDelay(fl);
    //variable++;
}
```

In the exit_toMovePallet block, the forklift is told which area of the pallet movement flow to enter:

```
if (agent.v_movementNbr==1) {
    enter_moveStoreRawMat.take(agent);
} else if (agent.v_movementNbr==2) {
    enter_moveStoreMinIng.take(agent);
} else if (agent.v_movementNbr==3) {
    enter_moveStorePreBulk.take(agent);
} else {
    traceln("Invalid movement type");
}
```

[image]